# How to read values into a buffer that lives in a struct?

Tags: rust

I have a file that I'm looking to read and I want to create a reusable struct for information important to parsing / reading information in the file.

The struct I have is as follows:

```rust
 struct InfoBytes {
    name: &'a str,
    offset: i64,
    values: Vec<u8>,
}
```

my goal is to create a loop where I iterate across these objects and read the exact bytes of length == values buffer.

the problem i'm running into is that I'm not sure how to effectively do that, cause I'm running into mutability errors when executing the following scenario...

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom},
};

trait ReadAtPosition {
    fn read_at_position(&mut self, offset: u8, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<()>;
}

impl ReadAtPosition for File {
    fn read_at_position(&mut self, offset: u8, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset.into()))?;
        self.read_exact(buffer)
    }
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::open("foo.xd")?;

    let header = vec![
        InfoBytes  { component: "info0", offset: 0x00, values: vec![0u8; 0x02] },
        InfoBytes  { component: "info1", offset: 0x02, values: vec![0u8; 0x0C] },
    ];

    // loop across the header vector
    for bytes in header.iter() {
        file.read_at_position(bytes.offset, bytes.values);
    }

    println!("{header:?}");
```

I keep getting errors of the nature: `consider mutably borrowing here with &mut` , and then when doing that running into the classic

`cannot borrow bytes.values as mutable as it is behind a & reference`.

What concepts am I missing here? Am I thinking about how to create the struct in the wrong way? Or is there some kind of core rust thing I'm getting wrong.

Any and all help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What concepts am I missing here?

`header.iter()` gives you an `Iterator<Item=&InfoBytes>`, so `bytes: &InfoBytes`, therefore you have no way to acquire an `&mut bytes.values`.

Use `iter_mut()`.